# How do I customise the generation of the EF 5 T4 model and context generation templates?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, t4

Every time I add an EDMX model o DB first data model to my project, EF generates two T4 templates, one to generate the domain models, and one to generate the DbContext. Then I have o modify these templates before generating all my classes. How can I modify the generation of these two T4 templates, not the modules output by these templates themselves?

Example: After generating a **Sample.edmx** DB first data model, under **Sample.edmx** we find a file called **Sample.Context.tt**. This file contains the line:

```
const string inputFile = @"Sample.edmx";
```

I need this string to be `@"..\..\Sample.Repository\Data\Sample.edmx"`. Right now, every time I generate a new data model, I have to open **Sample.Context.tt** and change this line of code. I want to find what generates that line and modify that, so the correct path to the edmx is generated every time.

Comment: So you want to modify the item template?

Comment: I want to modify the template that generates the Context.tt template. I need to make it point to a non-default edmx file location.

Comment: Is is so big problem to change just single value in the template? The template should be placed somewhere in VS installation folder - try Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Data

Comment: Thank you. Make this an answer and I'll accept it. Explain how, instead of hard-coding the edmx path and properly using the variable template's line `const string inputFile = @"$edmxInputFile$";` and I'll throw in a generous bounty.

Comment: That's why I posted it as an comment - I'm not sure how to replace the constant.

Comment: What do you want to modify it to to and why you cannot do it in the template (i.e. what information you are missing)?

Comment: @Pawel The location of the edmx file. I generate the models in a different project to the edmx file, but the template expects the edmc in the same directory as the template.

Comment: The thing I am missing is why you just can't remove remove the `const` in the template and then do `inputFile += myDirectory + inputFile`?

Comment: @Pawel My main issue was I didn't know where the template was. Now Ladislav Mmka has told me and I am solving the problem.